# How to map Pause/Break-Key in vim

Tags: vim

In search for a not used key in my vim environment, I found the <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key. Is it possible to map this key in vim?

The OS (Ubuntu/Mate) does not seem to catch the key. A test with `xev` revealed the following code for the key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
root 0xca, subw 0x803726, time 140830591, (148,44), root:(2939,505),
state 0x0, keycode 127 (keysym 0xff13, Pause), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

But a test with `:noremap <Char-127> :help Char<CR>` does not work. If it is not possible to map the key, is there a way to find out, which keys can be mapped in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and press the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key after entering `noremap`.

On my system, the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key is mapped to octal code 035 (decimal 29), so `:noremap <Char-035> k` maps <kbd>Pause</kbd> to the <kbd>k</kbd> key.

See below from Vim help:

```
There are three ways to map a special key:
1. The Vi-compatible method: Map the key code.  Often this is a sequence that
   starts with <Esc>.  To enter a mapping like this you type ":map " and then
   you have to type CTRL-V before hitting the function key.  Note that when
   the key code for the key is in the termcap (the t_ options), it will
   automatically be translated into the internal code and become the second
   way of mapping (unless the 'k' flag is included in 'cpoptions').
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps to find out, that the key is probably catched by the OS. Using CTRL-V with Pause does not work on my system whereas other keys  are working fine in this combination.

Comment: What do you see in your terminal if you key Ctrl+q and then the Pause key and hit enter? I see `$'\035': command not found`, which I can then use to find the octal representation for the `map` command.

Comment: On my system, Ctrl+] is equivalent to the Pause key.

Comment: It happens exactly nothing. But it seems to be an issue with the terminal emulator (even with `xterm`). I tried it with `gvim` and your solution works perfectly. It results in `:nnoremap <F21>`.

Comment: What about Ctrl+v and then the Pause key in the terminal?

Comment: Ctrl+v and the Pause key does not have a single effect in the terminal, as if I would not have pressed a key at all. Perhaps it is an terminal compatibility issue where the pause/break key has a special meaning to pause on long running lists?